# ExtJS Search Datastore for value

Tags: search, extjs, find, datastore, findby

How do I search a datastore for a specific record?  I've tried find() and findBy(), but both return -1.

```
var index = clientStore.find('ClientID', '37');
```

I have a combo box with a list of clients.  What I want is to be able to set a default value on that combo.  I have the value setting correctly using setValue and I can even set the display value using setRawValue, but I can't seem to query the datastore based on the clientID and get the company name to use in setRawValue.

Does that make sense?

Here's the datastore code in response to the questions below (sorry it wouldn't let me paste it there)

```
var frmClientStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    id: 'frmClientStore',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'url here', 
        method: 'POST'
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'rows',
        id: 'recordID'
    },[
        {name: 'recordID', type: 'int', mapping: 'recordID'},
        {name: 'ClientID', type: 'int', mapping: 'clientID'},
        {name: 'CompanyName', type: 'string', mapping: 'companyName'}
      ])
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that defines your store?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that line and examine the `data` property of the `clientStore`, does it include a record with a `ClientID` property equal to `'37'`? My suspicion would be that it doesn't, and that's the issue you need to address.

Comment: The datastore code appears to be missing from your comment. What are the fields listed in your data store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your configuration. First of all the `id`-property of the read should be the `idProperty`-property. The the `id`-property of the store should be the `storeId`-property (`id` is deprecated). And then your variable is called `frmClientStore` while you're referencing `clientStore` in your code (might be a typo).

```
var frmClientStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    storeId: 'frmClientStore',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'url here', 
        method: 'POST'
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'rows',
        idProperty: 'recordID'
    },[
        {name: 'recordID', type: 'int', mapping: 'recordID'},
        {name: 'ClientID', type: 'int', mapping: 'clientID'},
        {name: 'CompanyName', type: 'string', mapping: 'companyName'}
      ])
});
```

And finally: are you sure, your store has been loaded when you try to retrieve records from it?

Try

```
frmClientStore.load({
    callback: function(rs) {
        console.log(rs);
        console.log(this.find('ClientID', '37'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Got it working! I changed the datastore as you suggested, but it still would not find the record.  However, it found it just fine in the callback function of the load. If I put all the code in there, it works perfectly. But if I load the store, and THEN try to search, it finds nothing. That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I've only been using ExtJS for about 2 weeks, so who knows. Anyway, thank you very much, and thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: You always habe to keep the asynchrony of all remote operations in mind - that's a big problem when starting with ExtJS or JavaScript in general. Loading the store always occurs outside the regular program flow so you need the notion of callbacks.

Comment: You've been a huge help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you've listed should be correct. However, I should point out that the field name is case sensitive. It is also possible that it is searching for a string (as you've listed) instead of a number (which may be what you want).

Supposing that '`ClientID`' is the correct field name, you should try the following:

```
var index = clientStore.find('ClientID', 37);
```

**EDIT**

Also, I've just noticed that something looks off about your JsonReader. Shouldn't it be more like this:

```
//...
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'rows',
    id: 'recordID'
    fields: [ //list fields here as part of the JsonReader
        {name: 'recordID', type: 'int', mapping: 'recordID'},
        {name: 'ClientID', type: 'int', mapping: 'clientID'},
        {name: 'CompanyName', type: 'string', mapping: 'companyName'}
    ]
})
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways, with the same results unfortunately.

Comment: What results do you get if you do `frmClientStore.getRange()`?

Comment: I first thought that the reader definition was wrong too, but actually `Ext.data.DataReader` also can take two arguments, the configuration without a `fields`-property and an array of field definitions.